# Insert text from an Edit into any window where the mouse pointer is

Tags: delphi, text, insert

How can I insert the text from an Edit control into any window where the mouse pointer is, without using the clipboard and/or window handle.

I am using Delphi 7.

Comment: David's solution is great (+1) if you REALLY want to send to wherever the mouse pointer happens to be.  I suspect that it's more useful to send to the window that has the input focus, which may be the same, or if you're one of those people who likes to push the mouse cursor out of the way when they type or read, it may be somewhere totally different.

Comment: +1 for going out of your way to avoid (ab)using the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks, but i still have troubles with wource code. I know it`s simple, but my programming level is totally begginer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Call [`GetCursorPos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648390%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find out where the cursor is.
2. Call [`WindowFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633558%28VS.85%29.aspx) to find the window under the cursor.
3. Send an [`EM_REPLACESEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761633%28VS.85%29.aspx) message to replace the selection in that window. If nothing is selected then the text will be inserted at the caret.

**Note:** Be prepared for this to fail more commonly than it succeeds. Many applications don't used windowed edit controls. For a more robust solution you should look into [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

---

You asked for some code. Here's what it would look like:

```
var
  Pos: TPoint;
  Target: HWND;
...
if not GetCursorPos(Pos) then
  RaiseLastOSError;
Target := WindowFromPoint(Pos);
if Target<>0 then
  SendMessage(Target, EM_REPLACESEL, ord(True), LPARAM(PChar(Edit1.Text)));
```

If the window underneath the cursor is not an edit window, this will, probably, be benign.

Comment: I have understand the stucture.

Comment: One more question: how can i grab the text from tEdit not only orc symbol like "X"  SendMessage(h,WM_CHAR,Ord('x'),0);  ?
Thank you.

Comment: `code` h:DWORD; 


   GetCursorPos(pt);
   h:=WindowFromPoint(pt);  hope I`m on the right way?

Comment: I don't understand this. You can't ask this in a comment. Either ask a new question or edit this one. But make it a new question if it isn't intimately tied to this question.

Comment: It`s so amazing! It works!!! I am very happy. I wish i would send you, but the little program on Russian. Soon i will translate it. I will never forget you contribution in my dream. Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm pleased you are happy. You can accept the answer by making the big tick go green! :-)

Comment: Now i have a new problem: text from tEdit can insert everywhere - like Notepad, Icq. BUT not is Firefox, Google Chrome. What it may be? Thank you.

Comment: I already answered that in my note. Those apps don't use windowed controls. You need to use UI Automation or some other accessibility API.

Comment: I have learned the previous link about UI Automation. There is a lot of information, that my language experiens can't deal with that. Also i haven't seen any word about Delphi. It is hard to add UI Automation to Delphi and to my Project? I'm really this, may future depends on it :), i hope. I can return you kindness. I am much obliged to you.

Comment: What you are attempting to do is really hard. I can't help in comments and I don't know enough about UI Automation or the alternatives in general in any case.